# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'SKNode'

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode7

There is an issue on last line. How can I fix that? Issue says ''Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'SKNode'. '' Here is my code :

```
import SpriteKit

let BallCategoryName = "ball"

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

You are using `self` before the **object initialisation**.

Infact writing this

```
let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
```

is equals to writing this

```
let ball = self.childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
```

But during the properties initialisation the current instance of `GameScene` does not exists yet! So there's no `self` yet.

And this is a good thing because if the compiled had allowed this code, it would have crashed at runtime since there is no `ball` node in you `Scene` yet (again because there is no Scene yet).

### Solution

I suggest you to

1. turn your **stored property** into a **computed property**
2. use a **lowercase character** for the first name of a property like this `ballCategoryName`
3. prefer **conditional casting** (as? instead of as!)
4. turn the global constant `ballCategoryName` into a **stored property**

### The code

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let ballCategoryName: String = "ball"
    var ball: SKSpriteNode? {
        return childNodeWithName(ballCategoryName) as? SKSpriteNode
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will consider your advices.

Comment: I would think that the init should handle this but alas, it quickly got complicated with coder: etc and I so couldn't figure it out.  I've just used this method in Swift 3.0 and it still works.  Thanks.